# How to make your own Tempeh?

Tags: asian-cuisine, soy, indonesian-cuisine

I'm looking for information on Tempeh, especially how one make it themselves. Any info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean tempeh?

Tempeh is a fermented soybean product, grainier and denser than tofu. Making it requires a starter to help it ferment.

[Recipes](http://www.tempeh.info/) can be found here.

Otherwise, you'll have to move to Arizona.

Answer (score 1):

Tempe is a fermented with the fungus Rhizopus oligosporus, you will need to find a strain or starter to make it in your home.  Once you have that, some boiling and some vinegar and a day and a half later you have tempeh.

Comment: Sorry for my misspelling. Any recipes on using it?

Comment: Sorry @abe, i'll be happy to help you fix any recipes that you find but we don't really do recipes exchanges here.  It is a javanese product so I would start looking for recipes there.